# Calling specific methods between classes

Tags: java, class, methods

Help! I dont know much about java but im trying to create a small program where people can buy items and the stock should update depending on their purchase. I have 2 different classes but what im trying to do is that i want to get the amount of items the user purchases from one class and use that number to update the stock in another class - Here is the section of my code in which i am struggling with

Code for Purchasing Item

```
public class PurchaseItem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField ItemNo = new JTextField(5);                                      //Adds a text field named ItemNo
JTextField AmountNo = new JTextField(5);                                    //Adds a text field named AmountNo
TextArea information = new TextArea(6, 40);                                 //Adds a text area named Information  
TextArea reciept = new TextArea (10,50);                                    //Adds a text area named Reciept
JButton Check = new JButton("Check");                                       //Adds a button named Check
JButton Buy = new JButton("Buy");                                           //Adds a button named Buy
DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£#,##0.00");                      //For output to display in decimal and pounds format




public PurchaseItem() {                                                     //PurchaseItem class

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());                                     //Adds a new layout for PurchaseItem

    JPanel top = new JPanel();                                              //JPanel is a a container for other components
    top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));                       //It is set to the center of the frame
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();                                           //JPanel is a a container for other components
    bottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));                    //It is set to the center of the frame
    bottom.add(Buy);                                                        //Insert the "Buy" JButton on the frame
    this.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                                   //Button goes at the bottom of the frame

    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 250);                                          //Sets the bounds of the frame
    setTitle("Purchase Item");                                              //Sets the title of the frame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                      //Default option to exit frame is through button and not X sign

    top.add(new JLabel("Enter Item Key:"));                                 //Add a new JLabel at the top of the frame
    top.add(ItemNo);                                                        //Set the ItemNo Text Field at the top of the frame
    top.add(new JLabel ("Enter Amount:"));                                  //Add a new JLabel at the top of the frame
    top.add(AmountNo);                                                      //Set the AmountNo Text Field at the top of the frame
    top.add(Check);                                                         //Set the Check Button at the top of the frame

    Buy.setText("Buy"); Buy.setVisible(true);                               //Makes the text of the Buy Button visible

    Check.addActionListener(this);                                          //Add an ActionListener to the Check Button
    Buy.addActionListener(this);                                            //Add an ActionListener to the Buy Button

    add("North", top);
    JPanel middle = new JPanel();                                           //JPanel is a a container for other components
    middle.add(information);                                                //Set the Information Text Area at the middle of the frame
    add("Center", middle);

    setResizable(false);                                                    //Makes the frame not resizeable
    setVisible(true);                                                       //Makes the frame visible
}
@Override                                                                   //Overrides the method of the PurchaseItem class to identify mistakes and typos    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                //actionPerformed class. This is called when the actionListener event happens

    String ItemKey = ItemNo.getText();                                      //String for getting the user input from the ItemNo Text Field
    String ItemAmount = AmountNo.getText();                                 //String for getting the user input from the AmountNo Text Field
    String Name = StockData.getName(ItemKey);                               //String for getting the name of the item from StockData

    int Amount = Integer.parseInt(ItemAmount);                              //Convert String ItemAmount into an Integer variable named Amount

    int NewStock = StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey) - Amount;                 //Integer named NewStock. NewStock is the current stock(from StockData) minus the Amount 

    double Total = Amount * StockData.getPrice(ItemKey);                    //Double named Total. Total is the Amount multiplied by the price of the item(from StockData) 

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                                  //Calendar named cal. getInstance is used to get the current time

    SimpleDateFormat Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");             //SimpleDateFormat named Date. It is used to display the date
    SimpleDateFormat Time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");               //SimpleDateFormat named Time. It is used to display the time


    if (Name == null){                                                      //If the Name is invalid and has no return value
       information.setText("There is no such item");                        //Display the message on the Information Text Area
    }
    else if (Amount > StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey)) {                     //Else if the Amount(User Input) is more than the quantity of the item(from StockData)
    information.setText("Sorry there is not enough stock available");       //Display the message on the Information Text Area
}
    else {                                                                  //Otherwise                                                            
        information.setText(Name + " selected: " + Amount);             //Add the Name and the Amount of the item on the Information Text Area
        information.append("\nIndividual Unit Price: " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)));   //On a new line add the individual price of the item on the Information Text Area in a pound format(£)
        information.append("\nCurrent Stock Available: " + StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey));             //On a new line add the current quantity available according to StockData on the Information Text Area
        information.append("\nNew Stock After Sale: " + NewStock);                                      //On a new line add the NewStock on the Information Text Area
        information.append("\n\nTotal: " + Amount + " Units" + " at  " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)) + " each");     //On two new lines add the Amount plus the item price(from StockData). This becomes the Total
        information.append("\n= " + pounds.format(Total));                  //On a new line display the Total in a pounds format(£) on the Information Text Area
    }        
    if (e.getSource() ==  Buy) {                                            //If the user clicks the Buy Button
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Buy " + Amount + " Units" + " for " + pounds.format(Total) + "?");      //Show a confirm dialog asking the user to confirm the purchase with a Yes, No, or Cancel option   
        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {                           //If the user clicks Yes on the confirm dialog
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();                                       //Add a new JFrame called frame2
        TextArea Reciept = new TextArea ("Receipt For Your Purchase", 20,40);       //Add the Receipt Text Area onto frame2 and show the message
        Reciept.append("\n\nTime: " + Time.format(cal.getTime())); Reciept.append("\nDate: " + Date.format(cal.getTime()));     //On seperate lines add the Time and the Date (from Calendar)
        Reciept.append("\n\nYou Have Purchased The Following Item(s): ");   //Display the message
        Reciept.append("\n\n" + Name + "\n" + Amount + " Units" + "\n" + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)) + " each");                                 //On a line add the Name and Item Amount followed by the item price (from StockData) on a new line                          
        Reciept.append("\n\n\n" + Amount + " Unit(s)" + " at " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)) + " each" + "\nTotal = " + pounds.format(Total));   //After 3 lines display the Item Amount and the item price on the same line. On a new line display the Total in a pounds format
        Reciept.append("\n\n\nThank You For Your Purchase" + "\n\nGoodbye :)");          //Show a message on two seperate lines
        frame2.pack(); frame2.setSize(375, 380); frame2.setLocation(250, 250); ;frame2.setTitle("Receipt");     //Sets the size, the location, and the title of frame2
        frame2.setVisible(true); frame2.setResizable(false);                //sets frame2 so that it is visible and not resizable
        frame2.add(Reciept);                                                //Display the Reciept Text Area on frame2
        frame2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));                //It is set to the center of the frame


        }else{                                                              //Otherwise
            if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){                         //If the user clicks No or Cancel on the confirm dialog
                                                                            //Do nothing
            }
        }
```

Code for Checking Stock

```
public class CheckStock extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextField stockNo = new JTextField(7);                                     //adds a text field for user input
JTextField AmountNo = new JTextField(5);
TextArea information = new TextArea(6, 40);                                 //adds a text area for the output    
JButton check = new JButton("Check Stock");                                 //adds a button with the text "Check Stock"
 JButton Clear  = new JButton();
DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£#,##0.00");                      //for output to display in decimal and pound format


public CheckStock() {                                                       //"CheckStock" class
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());                                          //adds a new frame for "CheckStock"
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 220);                                          //sets the size and location of the frame
    setTitle("Check Stock");                                                //sets the title of the frame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                      //user has to click on "Exit" button instead of X sign

    check.addActionListener(this);                                          //adds an action listener for the "check" button so when clicked by user, "actionPerformed" class is called
    JPanel top = new JPanel();                                              //JPanel is a a container for other components. It is used at the top of the frame
    add("North", top);
    top.add(new JLabel("Enter Item Key:"));                                 //adds a label at the top of tne frame
    top.add(stockNo);                                                       //adds the "stockNo" text field to the top of the frame       
    top.add(check);                                                         //adds the "check" button to the top of the frame 
    JPanel middle = new JPanel();                                           //JPanel is a a container for other components. It is used at the middle of the frame
    add("Center", middle);
    middle.add(information);                                                //in the middle of the frame, add the "information" text area

    setResizable(false);                                                    //frame is not resizable
    setVisible(true);                                                       //frame is visible
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                //this code is fired once the user runs the ActionListener
    String key = stockNo.getText();                                         //string named "key" for the stockNo 
    String name = StockData.getName(key);                                   //string named "name" for the stockData
    int Quantity = StockData.getQuantity(key);
    int NewStock;
    if (name == null) {                                                     //if there is no input in the text field
        information.setText("Enter Item Key");                              //display the message on the text area
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == check) {

           StockData.getQuantity(key);
           information.append( "" + StockData.getName(key));

        information.append("\n New Stock: " + StockData.getQuantity(key));                                                                   //otherwise
        information.setText(name);                                                  //display the name of the item
        information.append("\nPrice: " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(key)));   //display the price of the item using pound format
        information.append("\nPrevious Stock: " + Quantity);     //display the amount in stock for the item according to StockData
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Variable names in Java should be camelCase by convention, so it should be: JTextField amountNo = new JTextField(5); That won't solve your problem though...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialise the object `Update`: your line of code should be

```
PurchaseItem Update = new PurchaseItem();
```

(As another point I can't see any code that adds the JComponent you created (e.g. the buttons, the text fields,...) to the two frames of the respective classes or that displays the two frames; if it isn't included in your code be sure to add these pieces of code).
Finally, if you need a code that checks for changes in the value of `Updated`, here's the simplest (but not the only) technique you can use, creating a thread (see the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) to know what are threads and how to use them):

```
int refreshTime = 1000;    // Refresh time in milliseconds
boolean running = true;    // Set it to false if you want to stop the thread
Runnable r = new Runnable({
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            Thread.sleep(refreshTime);
            // Put here your code to update your frames or your variables
        }    
});
```

Comment: still doesnt make sense to me. I done what you first asked adding the jcomponents to the two frames. I used AmountNo in both classes as i need to get the information from the purchase class and display it on the checkstock class. im stuck after this

Comment: You will also need to add code to display the frames; remember that I posted only the code that is used to retrieve changes from the other class. If you are still stuck, I suggest you to learn how to use [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) first. Sorry but if I can't see your code and know what do you want from your progam I can't help you more.

Comment: Where is it? I don't see any link